# Python os.rename if file system is full

Tags: python, file-io, operating-system, filesystems

I'm asking this beacause there's no way to try it myself (if there's one share it please (:).

I'm doing some file handling with Python os library, specifically file moving/renaming with os.rename().

Python docs explains some of the exceptions this function might raise [here](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename), but do not say anything about a full file system case. My guess is it raises an IOError, is this right?

Cheers.

Comment: When the file system is full, all bets are off.  Your Python app could crash in very obscure ways because the OS can't create temporary files.  Why ask?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Basically I have a spool directory with files I need to process, once they're processed I need to move them to an archive directory cleaning up the spool directory (I can't delete them). This script is run by the cron daemon. I wanted to handle the full file system case and quit gracefully within my script so it does not do something bizarre.

Comment: A full file system already is something bizarre.  While graceful shutdown is desirable -- and certainly what you should code for -- all bets will be off.  Nothing trustworthy will happen.

Comment: Words from experience! You're right, the situation is bizarre from the very begining. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Well, not all is lost when the drive is full, at least as long as the OS still has some swap space. I wish every program that writes to disk would handle a full disk somewhat reasonably, ie tell the user and not just report some general error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice this should rarely come up, but if you want to test I'd recommend creating a small file system (I don't know what OS you are on, but this could be on a virtual partition, a RAM disk, a flash drive, etc.) and loading it up with garbage files to see what happens.  Something like this maybe:

```
aBigNumber = 100000000000000000000000000000000
counter = 0
while (True):
    counter += 1
    anotherFile = open(`counter` + ".txt", "wb")
    anotherFile.write("0" * aBigNumber)
    anotherFile.close()
```

When you get an exception, you should be able to verify that the disk is full and then you'll know what kind of error to expect.

Comment: +1: Clever.  Note that filling up the OS's "var" or "tmp" partition may have disastrous consequences.  You should not *expect* this error.  It is only only way to diagnose file system full.  Since the OS is likely to crash, odds are good that something weird (and irreproducible) will happen instead of this error.

Comment: Going to try it. I'll come back with the answer. Thanks buddy.

Comment: BTW, the partition is not a system partition like "var", it is used as storage only.

Answer (score 1):

You can test it by filling up a small partition and then try the file operations on the filled filesystem. On *nix systems you can mount a tmpfs; for windows maybe use a usb stick.